# removing Drm from kindle book help

Tags: 16.04

installed calibres with kindle-unpacking plugin. the installed DeDRM plugin. restarted calibres in debugging mode and found that DRM was not removed. i received this feed back from debugging.

```
calibre Debug log
calibre 3.39.1  embedded-python: True is64bit: True
Linux-4.15.0-45-generic-x86_64-with-debian-buster-sid Linux ('64bit', 'ELF')
('Linux', '4.15.0-45-generic', '#48-Ubuntu SMP Tue Jan 29 16:28:13 UTC 2019')
Python 2.7.15
Linux: ('debian', 'buster/sid', '')
Interface language: None
Successfully initialized third party plugins: DeDRM (6, 6, 1) && KindleUnpack - The Plugin (0, 81, 5)
calibre 3.39.1  embedded-python: True is64bit: True
Linux-4.15.0-45-generic-x86_64-with-debian-buster-sid Linux ('64bit', 'ELF')
('Linux', '4.15.0-45-generic', '#48-Ubuntu SMP Tue Jan 29 16:28:13 UTC 2019')
Python 2.7.15
Linux: ('debian', 'buster/sid', '')
Interface language: None
Successfully initialized third party plugins: DeDRM (6, 6, 1) && KindleUnpack - The Plugin (0, 81, 5)
Turning on automatic hidpi scaling
QGtkStyle could not resolve GTK. Make sure you have installed the proper libraries.
devicePixelRatio: 1.0
logicalDpi: 96.0 x 96.0
physicalDpi: 118.41774744 x 118.946341463
Using calibre Qt style: True
QGtkStyle could not resolve GTK. Make sure you have installed the proper libraries.
[0.00] Starting up...
[0.01] Showing splash screen...
[0.30] splash screen shown
[0.30] Initializing db...
[0.35] db initialized
[0.35] Constructing main UI...
Looking for desktop notifier support from: org.freedesktop.Notifications
org.freedesktop.Notifications found in 0.0 seconds
[1.93] main UI initialized...
[1.93] Hiding splash screen
[11.22] splash screen hidden
[11.22] Started up in 11.22 seconds with 1 books
['zenity', '--modal', '--file-selection', '--title=Select books', '--separator=\n', '--attach=52428814', '--filename=/home/aubrey/Downloads/.fgdfg.gdfhjdhf*&^839', '--file-filter=Books | *.lrf *.rar *.zip *.rtf *.lit *.txt *.txtz *.text *.htm *.xhtm *.html *.htmlz *.xhtml *.pdf *.pdb *.updb *.pdr *.prc *.mobi *.azw *.doc *.epub *.fb2 *.fbz *.djv *.djvu *.lrx *.cbr *.cbz *.cbc *.oebzip *.rb *.imp *.odt *.chm *.tpz *.azw1 *.pml *.pmlz *.mbp *.tan *.snb *.xps *.oxps *.azw4 *.book *.zbf *.pobi *.docx *.docm *.md *.textile *.markdown *.ibook *.ibooks *.iba *.azw3 *.ps *.kepub *.kfx', '--file-filter=EPUB books | *.epub *.kepub', '--file-filter=Kindle books | *.mobi *.prc *.azw *.azw3 *.kfx *.tpz *.azw1 *.azw4', '--file-filter=PDF books | *.pdf *.azw4', '--file-filter=HTML books | *.htm *.html *.xhtm *.xhtml', '--file-filter=LIT books | *.lit', '--file-filter=Text books | *.txt *.text *.rtf *.md *.markdown *.textile *.txtz', '--file-filter=Comics | *.cbz *.cbr *.cbc', '--file-filter=Archives | *.zip *.rar', '--file-filter=Wordprocessor files | *.odt *.doc *.docx', '--file-filter=All files | *', '--multiple']
DeDRM v6.6.1: Trying to decrypt Today's Technician_ Automotive Heating & Air Conditioning Classroom Manual and Shop Manual, Spiral bound Version.azw4
Using Library AlfCrypto DLL/DYLIB/SO
MobiDeDrm v0.42.
Copyright © 2008-2017 The Dark Reverser, Apprentice Harper et al.
Decrypting Mobipocket 4 ebook: Today's Technician: Automotive Heating & Air Conditioning Classroom Manual and Shop Manual, Spiral bound Version
Found 0 keys to try after 0.6 seconds
Crypto Type is: 2
DeDRM v6.6.1: Failed to decrypt with error: No key found in 0 keys tried.
DeDRM v6.6.1: Looking for new default Kindle Key after 0.6 seconds
DeDRM v6.6.1: Running kindlekey.py under Wine
DeDRM v6.6.1: Command line: 'WINEPREFIX="/home/aubrey" wine python.exe "/home/aubrey/.config/calibre/plugins/DeDRM/libraryfiles/kindlekey.py" "/home/aubrey/.config/calibre/plugins/DeDRM/libraryfiles/winekeysdir"'
/bin/sh: 1: wine: not found
DeDRM v6.6.1: Found and decrypted 0 key files
DeDRM v6.6.1: Ultimately failed to decrypt after 0.6 seconds. Read the FAQs at Harper's repository: https://github.com/apprenticeharper/DeDRM_tools/blob/master/FAQs.md
Running file type plugin DeDRM failed with traceback:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "site-packages/calibre/customize/ui.py", line 172, in _run_filetype_plugins
  File "calibre_plugins.dedrm.__init__", line 621, in run
  File "calibre_plugins.dedrm.__init__", line 571, in KindleMobiDecrypt
DeDRMError: DeDRM v6.6.1: Ultimately failed to decrypt after 0.6 seconds. Read the FAQs at Harper's repository: https://github.com/apprenticeharper/DeDRM_tools/blob/master/FAQs.md
Added Today's Technician: Automotive Heating & Air Conditioning Classroom Manual and Shop Manual, Spiral bound Version to db in: 1.8
Added 1 books in 3.3 seconds
```

Comment: Looks like you have an AZW4 file, a pdf file in a kindle wrapper. You will need the KindleUnpack plugin to strip it back to pdf.

Answer (score 0):

The Linux DeDRM Calibre plugin doesn't automatically detect and generate the decryption keys necessary to strip DRM. You have to add them yourself.

I did this on Linux Mint 19.3 but the principles should be the same.

### Prerequisites

Install Wine (follow this guide [here](https://wiki.winehq.org/Ubuntu))

Install Kindle Reader 1.17 using Wine and sign in to your account

### Install Python 2.7 and pycrypto with Wine

- Download the latest Windows X86 MSI [here](https://www.python.org/downloads/release/python-2716/)
- Download pycrypto-2.1.0.win32-py2.7.zip from [here](http://www.voidspace.org.uk/python/modules.shtml#pycrypto) and unzip it
- Install using Wine

  ```
   wine msiexec /i python-2.7.16.msi
   wine pycrypto-2.1.0.win32-py2.7.exe
  ```

### Create the Kindle decryption file

If you don't already have the DeDRM plugin, download it [here](https://github.com/apprenticeharper/DeDRM_tools/releases) and add it to Calibre.

- unzip DeDRM_tools_6.8.0.zip
- Next, unzip DeDRM_Plugin.zip
- Locate kindlekey.py in the unzipped folder. Then, create the .k4i file.

  ```
   wine python.exe kindlekey.py
  ```

You should see a message with something like "Key successfully retrieved to kindlekey1.k4i"

### Add the .k4i file to your DeDRM plugin in Calibre

- Open Calibre -> Preferences -> Plugins -> DeDRM -> Customize Plugin -> Kindle for Mac/PC ebooks
- Import the k4i file that was just created

And with that, you should be able to remove DRM from .azw files downloaded through your Kindle app.